# Inserting Element at the beginning of the last element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I got the following DOM:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="column">col1</div>
<div class="column">col2</div>
<div class="column">col3</div>
</div>
```

I want to add an element **BEFORE col3.**
This is what I tried:

```
$('.wrapper').find('.column').prepend("HOWDY");
```

But this adds the element before all three columns.

```
$('.wrapper').find('.column').last().prepend("HOWDY");
```

does not work, either

Comment: Have you attempted `.before()`?

Comment: `$('.wrapper').find('.column:last').before("HOWDY");`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4gZjH/

Comment: @OleAlbers Pretty much what adeneo just said.

Comment: `$('.wrapper').find('.column:last-child').prepend("HOWDY");`

Comment: For next time, adding something **before col3** and adding an element as the first child of col3 are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".wrapper .column:last-child" ).prepend("HOWDY");
```

Comment: thats the one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".wrapper").children(".column").last().prepend("<div>HOWDY</div>");
```

Look at following link: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/pvkvW/)